# How to set up custom bone objects like in the Blender free rigs "Rain" and "Vincent" or Rigify, but from scratch? (How the bones are grouped)

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

So I'm trying to learn how to rig characters and I know how to set up custom bones. But rigs I have downloaded and tried to understand always have circles around the hips, back, arms, legs etc, but there's always less circles than there are bones. So is each circle a group of bones? Also when I create a custom bone myself, the rotation is off. Anyway to fix that? I'm just trying to understand how professional rigs like that are constructed and what bones are grouped under each circle controller. Thank you everyone in advance for the help! And sorry if this is a dumb question!

Edit:
[image]

For example, this guy has 3 rings around his torso, but I know there are more bones than that. What are they controlling, and how to I see what bones they are controlling?

Thanks again

Comment: The circles are custom bone shapes.  Each circle represents only a single bone, not a group; other bones are probably hidden or on other bone layers.  You can adjust the rotation of a custom shape by editing the shape in edit mode.  It will make more sense if you spend some time investigating rigs with custom shapes disabled, which you can do by disabling shapes in properties/object data/viewport display.

Comment: I agree with the previous user, but I’ll also mention that those circle shapes are often driving other bones rotations with formulas or acting as IK targets rather than deforming the mesh directly themselves.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard and Nathan, thank you guys, I will have to do more learning in IK's and drivers then!